# Formatting in a Data.frame in R

Tags: r, functional-programming, format, dataframe, typeof

Hi I have Managed to pick the number of occurrence of certain values in a file in every row(I used "by" to achieve this and was adamant on not using a for loop)

```
         [,1]
test     1041
use      474
error    192
why      148
when     96
```

Now this is of type "integer" - andI want to convert this to a data.frame that looks like

```
   Key    value
1  test     1041
2  use      474
3  error    192
4  temp     148
5  remedy   96
```

I am just breaking my head over this - as I could not find a right conversion technique for the same

Comment: You can try `data.frame(your data object)` to convert into a data frame.

Then use `names(your data frame) <- c("key","value")` to name as headers.

Comment: It would be good to have an minimal reproducable example. The output of `str` applied to the object or command that gives you the above output might also already help.